# undefined reference on ubuntu using memcpy

Tags: c++, ubuntu, constants, memcpy

In the aData.h file I have

```
struct AnalysisData

{

    Myuint64 maxRegsNeeded; 
}
static const Myuint64 My_NA_Value_64 = (Myuint64) - 1;
```

Myuint64 is defined in the following way :

```
typedef unsigned long long Myuint64
```

If in the `aData.cpp` file I make :

```
AnalysisData d;
d.maxRegsNeeded = My_NA_Value_64;
```

It works ok.
but if in the `aData.cpp` I implement the function

```
setData(void* pD,size_t s)
{
memcpy(pD,&My_NA_Value_64 ,s);
}
```

if I implement that as :

```
setData(void* pD,size_t s)
    {
    Myuint 64 err = My_NA_Value_64;
    memcpy(pD,&err ,s);
    }
```

it is OK
The following code fails during the compilation,with undefined reference to `My_NA_Value_64` :

```
AnalysisData d;
setData(&d.maxRegsNeeded,sizeof(d.maxRegsNeeded));
```

What is the reason for that?And how can it be solved?

Comment: It [works for me](http://ideone.com/PoCU1V) when I make a self-contained program from your code fragments. Perhaps you could provide a complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Pick a `setData()`. You have 2 listed here and don't specify which is causing the error, saying *both* are "OK". Please remove what is *not* in your code. I *think* you're trying to say the first one fails the second one works. Also, you have only two files mentioned here, `aData.h` and `aData.cpp`. Consolidate the issue to two snippets. Finally, just for clarity, the failure is likely in the *link* phase; not compilation.

Comment: 1) Can you provide a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the problem. 2) Can we have the exact error message generated by the compiler.